# Question that has equalities to prove about variance.

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

> Let $X,Y$ be two discrete random variables with finite expected value and variance, 
> we define: $Var(Y|X=x)=E[(Y-E(Y|X=x))^2|X=x]$ for $x$ such that $P_X(x)>0$. 
> The variance of $Y$ given $X$: $Var(Y|X)=g(X)$ such that $g(x)=Var(Y|X=x)$. 
> Prove: 
> $Var(Y|X)=E(Y^2|X)-(E(Y|X))^2$ 
> $Var(Y)=E(Var(Y|X))+Var(E(Y|X))$

**My Attempt:**
The idea: Find $Var(Y|X=x)$ and substitute $X$. 
$Var(Y|X=x)=E[Y^2-2YE(Y|X=x)+(E(Y|X=x))^2 | X=x]=E(Y^2|X=x)-2E(Y|X=x)E(Y|X=x)+
(E(Y|X=x))^2=E(Y^2|X=x)-(E(Y|X=x))^2$ 
I have reached what needs to be proven, I wanted to ask, if it wasn't given that $Var(Y|X)=g(X)$ such that $g(x)=Var(Y|X=x)$, I couldn't just jump from here substituting $X$, like my question is the idea to substitute $X$ a general one or it's specific for this question. 
I got stuck in the second part, I'm not sure what to use right here to reach $Var(Y)$, I know that $E(E(Y|X))=E(Y)$, but I tried to use definition of variance, and I didn't know how to start.

$Var(Y)=E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2$
Any feedback is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The first part of your question is not really clear to me. If you could elaborate, then maybe I could edit my answer to include your question about the first part.

Comment: @BranBar It's alright, what I meant was am I always supposed to calculate say $E(X|Y=y) = g(y)$, and then substitute $Y$, $g(Y)=E(X|Y)$. and seems like this is the definition and how it's calculated. Correct me if I'm mistaken. And thanks alot for your help!

Comment: I would not phrase it as "that is what you always suppose to do". I think of the two as separate mathematical objects (although connected). $g(y) = \mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]$ is just a function of $y$ and $g(Y) = \mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ defines a random variable. Happy to help : ) good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part note that you can write,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\text{Var}(Y|X)] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[Y^2|X] - \mathbb{E}[Y|X]^2\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[Y^2|X]\right] - \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]^2\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[Y^2] - \left(\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]^2\right] - \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]\right]^2 + \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]\right]^2\right) \\
&= \mathbb{E}[Y^2] - \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]\right]^2 - (\text{Var}(\mathbb{E}[X|Y])) \\
&= \text{Var}(Y) - \text{Var}(\mathbb{E}[Y|X])
\end{align}

Now rearranging gives the desired result. Hope this helps.

Comment: I just noticed you may have a typo in your answer, last two lines $Var(E[X|Y])$ and it should be $[Y|X]$

Comment: @Pwaol Keen eye. I fixed it.